# is there any way to set the cursor style of a GWT button in code?

Tags: java, gwt

I have seen some details from

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.Cursor.html

Did not see any example using this. I have put css class style but still cursor does not get the required cursor style.
can any one give an example please.?

Comment: can you paste the code you have tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be helpful

```
button.getElement().getStyle().setCursor(Cursor.POINTER);
```

But gwt prefer css directly

and by adding css style to the button(`**preffered**`)

```
button.addStyleName(mybuttonStyle);


.mybuttonStyle{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: yeah, i have been using styles only. But somehow my button does show text as cursor style when i hover on it even thought my style has a mention `cursor: default !important`. Your guided way also i have tried but negative. :(

Comment: yes, as mentioned in my above comments.. Your guided way also i have tried but negative. :(

Answer (score 1):

In case this is a SmartGWT application and you want to set the cursor for a SmartGWT widget, you can use [Canvas.setCursor()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html#setCursor%28com.smartgwt.client.types.Cursor%29).

```
IButton button = new IButton("Hover over");
button.setCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR);
```

http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?p=68560